# Best approach to make many to many relation in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, many-to-many

I have two models for MongoDB

Musician and Album

A music album can be sung/played by one or more musicians.

A musician can contribute (sing or play) to multiple music albums.

Music album model :

```
  albumName: {
    type: String
  },
  releaseDate: {
    type: Date
  },
  genre: {
    type: String
  },
  price: {
    type: Number
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  songs: {
    type: Array
  }
```

Musician model :

```
  artistName: {
    type: String
  },
  artist_type: {
    type: String
  }
```

Can you suggest a way to implement a many-to-many relationship in MongoDB?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

As MongoDB is a NoSql database, It's inconvenient to expect ORM functionalities from it.

You can implement it using a different way, though.

You can save a `musician` model's array of objects into a music album model like the following schema.

```
  albumName: {
    type: String
  },
  releaseDate: {
    type: Date
  },
  genre: {
    type: String
  },
  price: {
    type: Number
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  songs: {
    type: Array
  },
  musician : {
    type: Array
  }
```

where musician field will look like :

```
[
 {
  "artistName" : "Swift taylor",
  "artist_type" : "english"
 },
 {
  "artistName" : "Justin Bieber",
  "artist_type" : "english"
 }
]
```